# How to store a zip file in document directory?

Tags: iphone, zip, nsdocumentdirectory

I am working on a webservice based app, in which after calling a web service method the response is zip file and I have to store this zip file into a document directory folder. Please explain me how to do it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can store zip in document directory using bellow code:-

```
 NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                           NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
                           NSString *setPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filname.zip];
                           NSData *data = .... // your Zip data
                           [data writeToFile:setPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```